# Rails: In a controller, add a value to the params submitted by a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

In my "Users" db I have "email", "name", and "position".

`Email` and `name` are submitted through a form, but `position` is determined in my controller before I write the row for the new user. How can I add `position` to my `alpha_user_params`?

```
def create
  position = User.order("position DESC").first
  # How can I add position to alpha_user_params????

  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    # success stuff
  else 
    # error stuff
  end
end

private
  def alpha_user_params
    params.require(:alpha_user).permit(:email, :producer, :position)
  end
```

Comment: is that an attribute for the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if `position` is an attribute for user, you can do:

```
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.position = position
  # @user.position = User.order("position DESC").first
  if @user.save
    # success stuff
  else 
    # error stuff
  end
```

This does not require you to add anything to your `alpha_user_params` method. Since, the `position` attribute is being generated by your controller and will not be added/modified by a user, I would advise you to keep this attribute inside your controller, itself.

`user_params` should only permit those attributes which will be input/modified by the user.

Comment: Nice, is it possible to add it to user_params to keep it concise?

Comment: @Stoic I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. Is it possible to add the parameter to the `user_params` and then, save all the parameters together by saving `user_params`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I used `before_create` in the model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

before_create :get_position

private

def get_position
  self.position = YourLibrary.position
end
```

This will add the position when the user is created. You can also use other callbacks like `before_save`, check [the active record documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)